Reported speech - pronoun change for "we"
An exercise on reported speech has the following:
Choose the correct answer:

David said, “Can we go tomorrow?”.
A. David said if we can go tomorrow.
B. David asked if we could go the following day.
C. David asked if we could go tomorrow.
D. David said whether we could go tomorrow.


Ref. promova.com
The rules for pronoun change in reported speech are straightforward: If the original sentence is in the first person, you change the pronoun to the third person. If the original sentence is in the second person, you change the pronoun to the third person.

As per the above rule, the pronoun "we" shall change to "they"..
However, 'they' is not among the options provided. How to choose the correct answer?
Edit 1

In the question object is not there in reporting clause. Is there any rule, how to assume an object?
How would assuming different objects affect the answer?
A. David asked me
B. David asked John.
C. David asked his family.(plural)


Collins Dictionary has this definition for we:

the persons speaking or writing
used to refer to the speaker or writer and another or others, sometimes including those addressed

Hence ‘we’ is possible.  The rest of the analysis is probably not in your question, and I would not elaborate.

Unfortunately, it's not that straightforward. David said "we"; that means David and some other people. Is the speaker one of them? What about the person being spoken to?
Let's make up a scenario. David, John, and Tim are brothers. They want to go somewhere "tomorrow"; those three are the "we" that David refers to.

John reports David's speech to the boys' father: "David asked if we could go tomorrow." John uses "we" because he's part of the group.
The father reports David's speech to the mother: "David asked if they could go tomorrow." The father uses "they" because he's not part of the group.
The father reports David's speech to the third brother, Tim: "David asked if you could go tomorrow." The father uses "you" (meaning 2nd person plural) because Tim is part of the group.*

Not only is the site's summary too simple, the question is hard to answer too. Option C is a perfectly valid option if the speech is reported in the same day, while "tomorrow" is still tomorrow. But if a day has passed, option B is needed.
It might be a good idea to learn from a different source. The suggestion "If the original sentence is in the first person, you change the pronoun to the third person" just isn't always true. What if David said "I want to leave tomorrow." David could then report his own speech! And he would not use third person; he would say "I said I wanted to leave tomorrow."
This page offers some "rules" for these pronouns that are a bit more complex but more thorough.

From the list given, the best answer is B. But depending on context it could be different, and you probably need a more complete language guide.
Consider these two cases:

David and John were planning a trip to the movies. David said, "Can we go tomorrow?"

David and I were planning a trip to the movies. David said, "Can we go tomorrow?"


There is only a one word difference in those two sentences, but it has a big effect when we change to reported speech. This is because sentence 1 is written in the third person, while sentence 2 is written in the first person. The result is:

David and John were planning a trip to the movies. David asked if they could go the following day. (they because it refers to David and John.)

David and I were planning a trip to the movies. David asked if we could go the following day. (we because it refers to David and me.)


So in order to answer the exercise as intended, you have to assume that the context is a first-person piece of writing.

Special case of pronoun change in Reported speech.
As per the pronoun change rule in indirect speech - "The first person in direct speech changes as per the subject of the speech..".
But in this case I think the first person in direct speech changes as per the object (me) of the speech..
Explanation -
Reference English Grammar and Composition - Rajendra Pal
Page - G138

One has to be a little careful while changing the personal pronoun we . It can be retained as we or changed to you or they depending upon the relationship of the speaker, the person(s) addressed and the person reporting the speech.
1.Direct : He said to me, "We should have tried harder.".
Indirect: He told me that we should have tried harder..
2.Direct : He said to you, "We should have tried harder.".
Indirect: He told you that you should have tried harder..
3.Direct : He said to John, "We should have tried harder.".
Indirect: He told John that they should have tried harder..
4.Direct: The Prime Minister said, "We, the members of the ruling party should be united.".
Indirect: The Prime Minister said that they, the members of the ruling party, should be united..
5.Direct : The Prime Minister said, "We should be united to corruption tooth and nail.".
Indirect: The Prime Minister said that we should be united to corruption tooth and nail..

Reference English Grammar and Composition - Rajendra Pal
Page - G138
